# What are the published Bitcoin addresses of the Binance 7000 BTC hack from 2019 May?

Tags: binance, taint-analysis, hack

Binance got hacked of 7000 BTC in May of 2019. I'd imagine all the chain analysis companies are tracking these **tainted** Bitcoins to see if it hits any exchanges for selling. What are these address? Is there a visual graph of where it has ended up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article on Coin Telegraph](https://cointelegraph.com/news/bitcoin-stolen-in-binance-hack-moved-to-seven-addresses)  claims that [this is the transaction](https://www.blockchain.com/en/btc/tx/e8b406091959700dbffcff30a60b190133721e5c39e89bb5fe23c5a554ab05ea) spending the 7074 BTC.  You can follow the amounts from there.  Here is a tree chart: https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tree/444776063